# Parse a key1="foo",key2="bar" CSV string into a Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, csv, dictionary

Please take the following string:

> cbr="LACbtn",detnumber="1232700",laclvetype="ANN=x",laccalcrun="2014-09-10",lacbutton="Y",lacaccdays="0.00000000",lacentdate="2014-03-31",lactotdays="32.00",laclastent="2014-04-01",lacsrvdays="3,4",status="ok"

Its output from a 3rd party SDK and we need to access the values in our .net application.

What objects are available in .net 2 to parse this string into a `Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)`?

For instance, we'd like to grab values using the key names, for instance:

```
Dim X = Whatever("detnumber") '#### Where X would then contain "1232700"
```

I started coding manual stuff to split on commas but this got messy when "," & "=" existed inside the quoted values, for example: `key1="foo,bar",key2="hello=Dorothy!"` & I thought to myself that something must already exist to parse this type of string?

I'm just not having much luck finding anything.

Suggestions in either vb.net or c# would be fine.

**String rules:**

The documenation is a bit poor (i.e. i dont know how double quote within a value is handled yet) but i can confirm the following:

- Keys are never quoted
- Keys never contain spaces
- comma can exist within value: `Key="Hello: something"`
- equals sign can exist within value: `Key="something=something"`
- Values are always quoted, an empty value is always `Key=""`
- one key = one value, a key will never have more than one value
- no white space exists outside the values
- Keys are variable and could be called anything, they could even exist within values.

Comment: Can you give the specifications on how the input is received? Are the key portions never quoted (and never have spaces), are the value portions always quoted, are there never spaces around the commas, etc...

Comment: your original example code should contain the strings that are problematic, so people understand the 'worst case' scenario!

Comment: values are always quoted? keys always have a value? values always have a key? i.e. would string ever be: `key1=value1,key2=,="value1","value3"`

Comment: Please also show the code you are currently using to try to parse these values. Should help provide more useful answers.

Comment: `var cbr = "LACbtn, detnumber = 1232700, laclvetype = ANN=x, laccalcrun = 2014-09-10, lacbutton = Y, lacaccdays = 0.00000000, lacentdate = 2014-03-31, lactotdays = 32.00, laclastent = 2014-04-01, lacsrvdays = 3,4, status = ok";
var splitCbr = cbr.Split(new[] { ',','=' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);` if it's consistent all the time you could just do the following however based on that string pattern it's very hard to determine if this is accurate or not

Comment: @Rufus Ive updated my question to include the "worst case scenario" in the main example string & ive also added 'String Rules' based on their rather terrible documentation.

Comment: This is a non-standard format.  You almost certainly aren't going to find a parser that already supports it; you'll need to write your own, or try to switch the format you're using to something more typical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, given that you have some strict rules around the input string format, this should do:

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> GetInputKeyValuePairs(string input)
{
    var inputKeysAndValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input)) return inputKeysAndValues;

    const char keyValueDelimiter = '=';
    const char itemDelimeter = ',';
    const char valueContainer = '"';

    var currentKey = string.Empty;
    var currentValue = string.Empty;
    var processingKey = true;
    var processingValue = false;

    foreach (var character in input)
    {
        if (processingKey)
        {
            // Add characters to currentKey until we get to the delimiter
            if (character == keyValueDelimiter) processingKey = false;
            else currentKey += character;
            continue;
        }
        if (processingValue)
        {
            // Add characters to the currentValue until we get to the delimeter
            if (character == valueContainer) processingValue = false;
            else currentValue += character;
            continue;
        }
        if (character == itemDelimeter)
        {
            // We're between items now, so store the current Key/Value, reset
            // them to empty strings, and set the flag to start processing a key.
            inputKeysAndValues[currentKey] = currentValue;
            currentKey = currentValue = string.Empty;
            processingKey = true;
            continue;
        }    
        if (character == valueContainer)
        {
            // We're at the first quote before a value, so ignore
            // it and set the flag to start processing a value
            processingValue = true;
            continue;
        }
    }

    // Add the last key/value
    if (currentKey != string.Empty) inputKeysAndValues[currentKey] = currentValue;

    return inputKeysAndValues;
}
```

Comment: This assumes that values cannot contain quotes, i.e: `funnyQuote="He said, "Something funny"",key="value"`

Comment: This works great - i later determined that double quotes within values are replaced with tabs (odd i know) so that wont be an issue. Thank you for the help!